# Redirect base domain to url with subfolder (nginx)

Tags: nginx

We currently have nginx running perfectly fine. We have a specific need for a rewrite, but I can't seem to get it working.

We want the following https://www.domain.com/ to be redirected to https://www.domain.com/xxx/ . But the redirect should only work if there is nothing behind the slash (or without the trailing slash too if possible).

I tried a few things like

```
rewrite ^ https://www.domain.com/xxx/ permanent;
```

but then I get too many redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your statement `rewrite ^ https://www.domain.com/xxx/ permanent;`, the `^` is a regular expression that matches **any** URI. You only want to match a very specific string, so you need to specify the start and end anchors.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/$ /xxx/ permanent;
```

The regular expression `^/$` matches the root URI for the website. All Nginx URIs have a leading `/`, and the root URI contains a single `/` (even though some browsers choose to hide it in the address bar).

It is not necessary to specify the scheme or hostname if they have not changed. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

---

Alternatively, the `location = /` statement also matches a single URI. For example:

```
location = / {
    return 301 /xxx/;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thank you. This has done the trick.